How to output value from Money field in Craft 4, without outputting the currency symbol
How can I output the value from a Money field in Craft 4, without outputting the currency symbol, as easily as possible?
Using: {{ entry.price }} Outputs: Error: Object of class Money\Money could not be converted to string.
I then tried using {{ entry.price|money }}, but that outputs the currency symbol too, e.g. £20.00
This is what I want to output, but I can't figure out how to do it:

20.00

The Craft CMS Money Field docs page isn't much help to me (as a non-dev) as it lacks example code snippets that I can easily see and use.
Thanks in advance for any help.
Stephen

This is how I solved it in a Craft project:
{% set moneyHelper = create('craft\\helpers\\MoneyHelper') %}
{{ moneyHelper.toDecimal(entry.price) }}

See MoneyHelper docs

Hi Jesse, thanks for your answer. I tried adding the exact code above into a template as my field is also named entry.price, but nothing was outputted at all. Any ideas?

I just tried it out and seems to work fine. Maybe a CMS version issue (i'm on Craft 5.4.2). Other than that, maybe worth debugging the MoneyHelper::toDecimal function from the vendor/ directory? Or reach out on the Craft discord why it would output blank?
